# How to Convert JSON into Customize Array in PHP?

Tags: php, json

Hi everyone I have a JSON something like this

```
{
"100": "Testing",
"200": "Usman",
"700": "User Test"
}
```

I need to convert it into like this in PHP.

```
[
["100", "Testing"],
["200", "Usman"],
["700", "User Test"],
]
```

Comment: And where is the problem?

Comment: Search `json_decode()`

Comment: @aldrin27 json_decode() not doing this. please check before anser

Comment: Please see Daan's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `json_decode` for decoding the json. Then loop through the decoded json and make a new array.

```
$json = '{
"100": "Testing",
"200": "Usman",
"700": "User Test"
}';

$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

$newArray = [];

foreach($decoded as $key => $value){
    $newArray[] = [$key, $value];   
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($newArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(100)
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Testing"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(200)
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Usman"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(700)
    [1]=>
    string(9) "User Test"
  }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in $newArray[] = [$key, $value];

Comment: Which php version are you using ?

Comment: Instead declaring new array with `[$key, $value]` you can do this: `array($key, $value)`.